# Show space in JTextField

Tags: swing, tabs, space, jtextfield

I am trying to show spaces and tabs in jtextfield, display space as little gray dot, and tabs as little gray arrows (like eclipse/netbean/microsoft word).

In this field and every space matters (even the trailing space counts), and I want to show this to the user.

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense. Could you more fully describe why you are trying to do? What do you mean by "show spaces and tabs"?

Comment: In eclipse/netbean (or even microsoft word) there is an option to display space as little gray dot, and tabs as little gray arrows.

Comment: Have you tried .replace(' ', '.')  ?  Did it work?

Comment: I want to show it in different color, so it won't be confused with other text.

Comment: I suppose you want to visibly render whitespace in the input field, without altering the underlying model. For example, [as seen in this editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDw3i.png). I think you would need to create a `JTextField` with a custom renderer.